# Having problems installing Brownie

Tags: brownie

I have been struggling installing brownie for while now and i cant seem to figure it out. I am quite new to all of this so all help is appreciated:) Running python 3.9.11. Using a an m2 mac with Ventura 13.0. Sorry if i am asking a stupid question.

```
    soldal@Sigves-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 -m pip install eth-brownie
Collecting eth-brownie
  Using cached eth_brownie-1.19.3-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Collecting aiohttp==3.8.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (337 kB)
Collecting aiosignal==1.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting asttokens==2.0.5 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached asttokens-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting async-timeout==4.0.2 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting attrs==22.1.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting base58==2.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached base58-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Collecting bitarray==2.6.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached bitarray-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (104 kB)
Collecting black==22.10.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached black-22.10.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting certifi==2022.9.24 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting click==8.1.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting cytoolz==0.12.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached cytoolz-0.12.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (367 kB)
Collecting dataclassy==0.11.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached dataclassy-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting eip712==0.1.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eip712-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting eth-abi==2.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_abi-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting eth-account==0.5.9 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.9-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting eth-event==1.2.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_event-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.3 kB)
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]==0.3.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_hash-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
Collecting eth-keyfile==0.5.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting eth-keys==0.3.4 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp==0.2.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting eth-typing==2.3.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_typing-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Collecting eth-utils==1.10.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting execnet==1.9.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached execnet-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting frozenlist==1.3.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (35 kB)
Collecting hexbytes==0.2.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting hypothesis==6.27.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached hypothesis-6.27.3-py3-none-any.whl (384 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna==3.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from eth-brownie) (3.4)
Collecting inflection==0.5.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached inflection-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting iniconfig==1.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1.tar.gz (41 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting lru-dict==1.1.8 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached lru-dict-1.1.8.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting multiaddr==0.0.9 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting multidict==6.0.2 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (29 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions==0.4.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting mythx-models==1.9.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached mythx_models-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting netaddr==0.8.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached netaddr-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting packaging==21.3 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting parsimonious==0.8.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pathspec==0.10.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pathspec-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting platformdirs==2.5.2 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached platformdirs-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pluggy==1.0.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.31 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.31-py3-none-any.whl (382 kB)
Collecting protobuf==3.19.5 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Collecting psutil==5.9.2 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached psutil-5.9.2.tar.gz (479 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting py==1.11.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached py-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting py-solc-ast==1.2.9 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached py_solc_ast-1.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting py-solc-x==1.1.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached py_solc_x-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.15.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.15.0.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pygments==2.13.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pygments-lexer-solidity==0.7.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pygments-lexer-solidity-0.7.0.tar.gz (7.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.9 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (81 kB)
Collecting pytest==6.2.5 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
Collecting pytest-forked==1.4.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pytest_forked-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Collecting pytest-xdist==1.34.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pytest_xdist-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting python-dotenv==0.16.0 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached python_dotenv-0.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pythx==1.6.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached pythx-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pyyaml==5.4.1 (from eth-brownie)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [62 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
      
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 318, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 548, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 586, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "/private/var/folders/8j/rb_4l20515xczszh2kx5qk540000gn/T/pip-build-env-ybsrvz33/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am not sure what to do and would appreciate the help because I am looking to develop using solidity and brownie seems to be the best option.

I am open to tips, suggestions, and constructive criticism

Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: You can go directly to the home page to get started

Comment: For python 3.12 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490435/attributeerror-cython-sources/77491847#77491847

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do it in virtual env. Here are steps that worked for me:

1. create requirements.txt file and put these lines in it:

black==22.10.0

brownie-token-tester==0.1.0

eth-brownie>=1.19.3

flake8==3.7.9

isort==4.3.21

2. install and switch to node 16.17.0
3. install ganache-cli, run this command:
   npm i -g ganache-cli@6.12.1
4. setup virtual env, Run this:
   python3 -m venv venv
5. Run this:
   source venv/bin/activate
6. finally run this:
   pip install -r requirements.txt

You should have brownie setup and can run/simulate transactions